# position: 'bottom' - Tab doesn't allow swiping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, reactjs-flux

Just pulled the newest version of "react-native-flux" for coding a little bottom-tab-bar...

```
react-native-router-flux v4.2.0-beta.2
```

Well the tab doesn't allow swiping to left and right when `tabBarPosition:'bottom'` was set.
Position top allows swiping.

So how do we solve this issue ? Any tricks or hacks for allowing swiping for a bottom bar ?

Answer (score 0):

try by setting swipeEnabled={true} in TabStack.

also try adding legacy={true} , it will work hopefully

Comment: Didnt worked either... but why doesn't the top-bar needs this set in order to enable swiping ?